# Uniform convergency of a given sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Consider the sequence of function $f_{n}(x)=n^{2}x\bigl(1-x^{2}\bigr)^{n}$. Is this sequence of function convergent uniformly in $[0,1]$ ?

We find that $f$ converges point wise to the function $f(x)=0$.

> $\mathbf {Method 1:}$ We find that, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx=\infty$$ but $$\int_{0}^{1}lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=0.$$ So $\bigl\{f_{n}(x)\bigr\}_{n}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ in $[0,1]$.

$\mathbf{Method 2:}$ We consider $\bigl|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\bigr|=g(x)(say)$. Then $g(x)=n^{2}x\bigl(1-x^{2}\bigr)^{n}$. We evaluate $g'(x)$ , $g''(x)$. For extreme point we put $g'(x)=0$ & we get the values $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}.$

Now , $g''(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})<0$. So,  $g$ attains maximum value at $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ & the maximum value is $$g(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})=\frac{n^{2}}{\sqrt 3}\bigl(\frac{2}{3}\bigr)^{n}=M_{n}.$$ 
As $M_{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ so $\bigl\{f_{n}(x)\bigr\}_{n}$ converge uniformly to $f(x)$.

> My question is " Why these two methods contradicts each other? " Where my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum for $x(1-x^2)^n$ is attained in the same point where the function $\log x+n\log(1-x^2)$ takes its maximum, i.e. in a zero of:
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2nx}{1-x^2}$$
i.e. in $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, so:
$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]} f_n(x) = \max_{x\in[0,1]} n^2 x(1-x^2)^n = \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n}\geq \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{(2n+1)e}}. $$

Comment: If we calculate the derivative without taking logarithm then where the problem?

Comment: @Panja.S.: I considered the logarithm just for making computations easier (at least to me), but obviously the location of the maximum is the same if we consider the roots of $f'(x)$.

Comment: But it is not the same. That's my question.

Comment: @Panja.S.:  If $f(x)>0$, the zeroes of $f'(x)$ *are* the same as the zeroes of $\frac{d}{dx}\log f=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. You computed the stationary point for $f_1$, but the location of the stationary point of $f_n$ is not the same for every $n$.

Comment: So the issue is that $g$ *does not* attain its maximum in $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x_n):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(n^{-1/2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2}\cdot e=\infty$$

$$\implies\:\:\exists\varepsilon>0:\:\:\forall N_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb N\:\:\exists x_n\in[0,1]\:\:\exists n\geqslant N_{\varepsilon}:\:|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\geqslant\varepsilon\\\iff f_n(x)\overset{\text{unif}}{\not\rightarrow}f(x).$$